# Porque este codigo no funciona en condicional?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
System.out.println("Insert el nombre del Programador");
            String program_name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Inserte el salario del nuevo programador");
            int program_salario = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Inserte el lenguaje favorito del nuevo programador");
            String program_fv = sc.nextLine();
 emlist.add(new Programador(program_name, program_salario, program_fv, Math.random() * 1000));
            System.out.println("Nuevo Programador añadido");
```

//
Me aparece en consola directamente, los dos primero sout, y tampoco parece que almacene las variables correctamente ya que por ejemplo en el primer caso puedo introducir un numero en vez de un String y el programa sigue..., sin embargo si lo hago fuera de un if o un switch, si funciona :/
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a usar scanners individuales para los String e Int.

```
System.out.println("Insert el nombre del Programador");
            String program_name = scString.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Inserte el salario del nuevo programador");
            int program_salario = scInt.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Inserte el lenguaje favorito del nuevo programador");
            String program_fv = scString.nextLine();
 emlist.add(new Programador(program_name, program_salario, program_fv, Math.random() * 1000));
            System.out.println("Nuevo Programador añadido");
```

Comment: Efectivamente.. cual es la explicacion? Que precauciones he de tomar con los scanner para que no me pase mas?

Comment: Pues no sabría decirte un porque concreto, lo busque hace tiempo pero ahora no lo recuerdo, te recomiendo usar siempre un scanner diferente en cuestión del tipo de dato, ya sea String, ind, decimal, etc.